# Capture up to three different kinds of dates?

Tags: regex, date, regex-group

I have this RegEx here

```regex
^([12]\d{3})(?:[.](10|11|12|(?:0[1-9]))(?:[.](30|31|(?:0[1-9])|(?:[12]\d)))?)?$
```

The purpose being to capture either: yyyy, yyyy.mm or yyyy.mm.dd as valid date strings for an input field. It does this fine, however, turns out it needs to be the other way around.

I have tried to reverse the process but I keep coming up short and can't quite figure it out. How would I make it capture: yyyy, mm.yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy as valid date strings?

(Should be mentioned that regex is essentially magic to me. I don't really get it intuitively.)

Comment: There is a subtle (but significant) edge case here, which makes using pure regex to validate dates difficult: February can have either 28 or 29 days, depending on whether the year is a leap year or not.  Consider using an API to validate your dates.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I do know of this edge case, however for the purposes of this validation it is not required to check for that. If I do have to check for it later, I will use an API to do so :) (any suggestions? it's Javascript hah)

Comment: A tiny point that doesn't directly help you: you can escape the `.` with `\.` instead of using the group `[.]`.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Still thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: What do you mean by reversing the process? Do you want to match 30, 30.10 and 30.10.2000 ?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Not exactly. I thought I described it in the question?

Comment: Your pattern matches the different formats and uses 3 capturing groups. But the full matches are `yyyy, mm.yyyy and dd.mm.yyyy`. Is that not the expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it is better to check for date validity with other tools than regular expressions.
I would suggest to use the following regex:
`^((\d{2})\.)?((\d{2})\.)?(\d{4})$`
where the 2nd, 4th and 5th capturing groups will correspond to respectively dd, mm and yyyy.

You can check the validity of these values afterwards.

If you still want  to do it entirely with one regex, you can go with the following:
`^((30|31|[012]\d)\.)?((11|12|0\d)\.)?(\d{4})$`
but it still doesn't cover the February 29th problem, nor the matching of 30/31 days months.

Comment: Thank you! I will check this out :)